# Laravel migrations: dropping a specific table

Tags: laravel, database-migration

Is there any way/laravel-command to drop a specific table from the production server?

Answer (score 16):

Set up a migration.

Run this command to set up a migration:

```
php artisan make:migration drop_my_table
```

Then you can structure your migration like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class DropMyTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // drop the table
        Schema::dropIfExists('my_table');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // create the table
        Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // .. other columns
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

You can of course just drop and not check for existence:

```
Schema::drop('my_table');
```

Read further in the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations

You may also have to consider dropping any existing foreign keys/indexes, for example if you wanted to drop a primary key:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('my_table', function ($table) {
        $table->dropPrimary('my_table_id_primary');
    });

    Schema::dropIfExists('my_table');
}
```

More in the docs in dropping indexes etc here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#dropping-indexes